# Get nearest objects according to time

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've two objects arrays in javascript :

the first one get weigths acquired by a sensor

```
{
    time : 'some timestamp',
    weigth : 1160
}
```

the second one get rfid acquired by another sensor

```
{
    time : 'some timestamp',
    rfid : 'some rfid identifer'
}
```

For each rfid identifier gotten I want to get the weigth before and after the acquired data time. And If I don't have any weigth in the array gotten after the rfid I got an undefined value.

Both arrays are sorted by time.

For now I have the current code :

```
var rfidNext = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.acquiredData.rfid.length; i++)
{
    var weigths = this.acquiredData.weigthLitter;

    var currentRfid = this.acquiredData.rfid[i];
    var weigther = weigths.find(w => w.time > currentRfid.time);

    if (!weigther)
        rfidNext.push(currentRfid);
    else
        toSend.events.push({
            // Some logic here        
        });
}
```

this code seems to get me the correct weigth taken after the rfid data, but I can't find a clean way to get the one before.

Edit : data example

```
[ { time: 1561458881523, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561458882212, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561458883941, value: '1000 0000 0000 0002' } ]

[ { time: 1561458881182, value: 2130 },
  { time: 1561458881584, value: 1000 },
  { time: 1561458882789, value: 2130 },
  { time: 1561458884599, value: 3290 } ]
```

With those data for example : the first rfid is taken between the first and the second weigth acquired, which means the animal got out of the box, the 2nd rfid shows that the animal came back in and the last one shows that the weigth get higher again, with another rfid so another animal came in the box.

Edit: Bigger dataset example

```
[ { time: 1561469442605, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561469463263, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561469503038, value: '1000 0000 0000 0002' },
  { time: 1561469524312, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561469530073, value: '1000 0000 0000 0002' },
  { time: 1561469551351, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561469552085, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561469579144, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561469627817, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561469629525, value: '1000 0000 0000 0002' } ]

[ { time: 1561469394648, value: 1000 },
  { time: 1561469443257, value: 2130 },
  { time: 1561469463268, value: 1000 },
  { time: 1561469503679, value: 2160 },
  { time: 1561469524962, value: 3290 },
  { time: 1561469530073, value: 2130 },
  { time: 1561469551358, value: 1000 },
  { time: 1561469552740, value: 2130 },
  { time: 1561469579144, value: 1000 },
  { time: 1561469628430, value: 2130 },
  { time: 1561469630175, value: 3290 } ]
```

To explain in details :

At the beginning no animal are in, weigth of 1000

then animal 1 come in : weigth of 2130

animal 1 get out : weigth of 1000

animal 2 get in : weigth : 2160

animal 1 get in : weigth of 3290

and so on...

So my goal is to find if the animal is getting inside or outside according to weigth variation and rfid readings.

Comment: can you add sample data array?

Comment: Yup, I will generate one :)

Comment: @Harish I've edited with a sample of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally manage to achieve it this way, using index (I felt kind of dumb for not thinking about that before but well, when you're focus in your idea that's sometimes hard to get another point of view)

```
    for (var i = 0; i < this.acquiredData.rfid.length; i++)
    {
        var weigths = this.acquiredData.weigthLitter;

        var currentRfid = this.acquiredData.rfid[i];
        var indexSup = weigths.findIndex(w => w.time >=  currentRfid.time);

        Log("RFID : " + currentRfid.value + "@" + currentRfid.time + " Before  :" + weigths[indexSup - 1].value+ "@" + weigths[indexSup - 1].time + " After :" + weigths[indexSup].value + "@" + weigths[indexSup].time);

        var evttype = weigths[indexSup - 1].value > weigths[indexSup].value ? 'exit' : 'entrance'; 
        toSend.events.push({
            type : evttype,
            bunnyId : currentRfid.value.toString(),
            value : currentRfid.time
        });

    }
```

And I manage to be sure in the rest of the simulation that data will be complete when I'm at this point of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to solve your scenario, take look on it
I iterated over `rfid` data, find `before` and `after` `time` and `weights`. Compared the values and depends on decision pushed the `msg` and `rfid` to `result` array

```
var acquiredData = {
    weigthLitter: [
  { time: 1561458881182, value: 2130 },
  { time: 1561458881584, value: 1000 },
  { time: 1561458882789, value: 2130 },
  { time: 1561458884599, value: 3290 }],

rfid: [ { time: 1561458881523, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561458882212, value: '1000 0000 0000 0001' },
  { time: 1561458883941, value: '1000 0000 0000 0002' } ]
}

var { weigthLitter, rfid } = acquiredData

var result = rfid.reduce((acc, el, id)=> {
   var currentRfid = el.value;
   var after = weigthLitter.find(w => w.time > el.time);
   var before = weigthLitter.find(w => w.time < el.time);


    if(rfid[id-1] === undefined || (rfid[id-1] &&  rfid[id].value === rfid[id-1].value)){ // checking rfid is same or undefined 
        if (before.value > after.value) {
            acc.push({rfid: el.value, msg: "animal got out of the box" })
        } else {
            acc.push({rfid: el.value, msg: "animal came back in" })
        }
     } else {
           acc.push({rfid: el.value, msg: "another animal came back in" })
     }
     return acc
     }, [])

     console.log(result) //[{"rfid":"1000 0000 0000 0001","msg":"animal got out of the box"},{"rfid":"1000 0000 0000 0001","msg":"animal came back in"},{"rfid":"1000 0000 0000 0002","msg":"another animal came back in"}]
```

Comment: That's almost what I was looking for indeed, thanks ! Just a question about the use of find() for before. If ther'es more than one values of weigth before the rfid time, the find will probably give me the first weigth which isn't maybe the last one before rfid acquisition ?

Also, I don't really need to check for rfid previous and after. I get data only if there are some rfid gotten and I also only get rfid data and no undefined values. The main goal is just to say: "Uh okay, I've read an RFID of this animal, and the weigth inside the box is now higher, so the animal got inside"

Comment: can you try same for data having 10-15 values, so that we can relate?

Comment: That should be possible, I'll edit the simulation process to do so.

Comment: I've added a bigger data-sets. Sorry for the long time. It helped me find a bug in the simulation that sometimes was missing some data ! :)

Comment: Hope you are near to your final solution.